# Cast string column to struct in a nested structure PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following schema:

```
|--items : array
   |-- element : struct
       |-- id : long
       |-- value : double        
       |-- stock : array
           |-- element : string
```

How can I access the stock column to cast it to a struct using `withColumn`?

I’ve tried with no success:

```
df = df.withColumn(
     ‘items’,
     F.col(‘items’).withField(
        ‘stock’,
        F.structure(
          F.lit(None).cast(‘long’).alias(‘id’),
          F.lit(None).cast(‘double’).alias(‘val’)   
        )
     )
)
```

My desired output schema is:

```
|--items : array
   |-- element : struct
       |-- id : long
       |-- value : double        
       |-- stock : array
           |-- element : struct
               |-- id : long
               |-- val : double
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform  "stock" from an array of strings to an array of structs

So you need to use the `explode` function on "items" array so data from there can go into separate rows.Then you need to use `withColumn` to transform the "stock" array within these exploded rows. Finally you need to use `collect_list` to reassemble the rows back into a single array.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    StructType,
    StructField,
    LongType,
    DoubleType,
    ArrayType,
    StringType,
)

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Nested Schema Transformation").getOrCreate()

# Sample Data
data = [(1, [(1, 1.0, ["a", "b"]), (2, 2.0, ["c", "d"])])]
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("id", LongType()),
        StructField(
            "items",
            ArrayType(
                StructType(
                    [
                        StructField("id", LongType()),
                        StructField("value", DoubleType()),
                        StructField("stock", ArrayType(StringType())),
                    ]
                )
            ),
        ),
    ]
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

# Explode 'items' array
df_exploded = df.select("id", F.explode("items").alias("item"))

# Transform 'stock' to desired schema
transformed_stock_schema = ArrayType(
    StructType([StructField("id", LongType()), StructField("val", DoubleType())])
)

df_transformed = df_exploded.withColumn(
"new_stock",
F.expr("transform(item.stock, x -> named_struct('id', CAST(x AS long), 'val', CAST(x AS double)))"))

# Collect back to original array format
df_final = df_transformed.groupBy("id").agg(
    F.collect_list(F.struct("item.id", "item.value", "new_stock")).alias("items")
)

# Show the result schema
df_final.printSchema()
```

The resultant schema is:

```
 root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- items: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- new_stock: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- val: double (nullable = true)
```

Comment: is there a way to drop the array field using drop command? I mean, considering the first schema, is there a way to drop the stock column? I tried using dropField, but with no success

Comment: I accepted your answer as correct and posted another question regarding my comment above.